# grep football player names with special characters

Tags: grep, git-bash

Sorry for asking so many questions recently.

I have another issues with grep in bash. (I am using gitbash)

When I try to use grep for names with special characters e.g.:

```
Nikola Boranijaševi
Niclas Füllkrug
Christian Groß
Anderson Gonçalves
Oliver Kahn
Manual Neuer
etc....
```

code I tested:

```
egrep -i "Nikola Boranijaševi|Niclas Füllkrug|Christian Groß|Anderson Gonçalves" playerlist.csv >>matches.csv
```

this returns nothing.

the same code works for players without any special characters.....

I even did a small test like:

```
egrep -aoi "Anderson Gonçalves" playerlist.csv >> matches.csv
```

but again this did not output anything

does anyone know how to use grep with special characters?

I read here on the forum  I should use double \ before special  characters so I tried the following to:

```
egrep -aoi "Anderson Gon\\çalves" playerlist.csv >> matches.csv
```

again no output... any ideas would be appreciated thanks!!

even a grep with a wildchard chaarcter replacement instead of ç in Anderson Gonçalves in grep would help.. thank you!!

Comment: Please take a look at [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: I am not sure what I did wrong? The code is in the code tag isn’t it? Can you please explain so I can fix it and learn for next time? Thanks!

Comment: All text blocks (e.g. sample input and expected output) also need to be in Code Blocks. I fixed that for you.

Comment: Regarding `special characters` - avoid using the word "special" to describe anything in software so you're forced to figure out what those things really are and so could then have more success googling for the right terms. The "special" characters you need to escape in a regexp are **regexp metachars** such as `.` and `*` if you want them to be treated literally, That has nothing to do with what you're trying to do. The characters you're referring to as "special" appear to be non-English (or maybe non-ASCII?) characters.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is use wild cards; it's not perfect, but it does work:

```
egrep -aoi "Nikola Boranija*|Niclas F*|Christian Gro*|Anderson Gon*" playerlist.csv >>matches.csv
```